# Правильно ли расставлены запятые в предложении? Нужно ли выделить запятыми "только что купленную"

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены запятые в предложении?

*И вот, наконец, взяв кредит, она въехала в свою **только что купленную** квартиру.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае ***свою*** и ***только что купленную*** — неоднородные определения. Поэтому дополнительных запятых не требуется.

Формально, мне кажется, можно счесть оборот *"только что купленную"* уточнением к *"свою"* и выделить запятыми, но это в вашем случае выглядит как-то неуместно.